# How to apply correlation after doing train_test_split?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have the following code where after splitting between training and testing, I perform feature engineering. With that I wanted to reduce the size of my base seeing which variables will have more correlation with other (most likely with the original variables) variables and with the target variable "Cover_Type".

How can I accomplish this after calling train_test_split and in the end of this code?

```
train, test = load_train_test_data(PATH)

variables = train.drop("Cover_Type", axis=1)
var_resp = train["Cover_Type"].copy()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(variables, var_resp, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

# Feature engineering:
# Hypotenuse_Distance_To_Hydrology - sqrt((Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology)^2 + (Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology)^2) using Pythagoras's theorem
# Hillshade_Mean - (Hillshade_9am + Hillshade_Noon + Hillshade_3pm)/3
# Is_Extremely_Stony - if Type_Soil 1, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 then 1 else 0
# Is_Very_Stony - if Type_Soil 2, 9, 18, 26 then 1 else 0
# Is_Rubbly - if Type_Soil 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 22 then 1 else 0
def add_features(data):
    data["Hypotenuse_Distance_To_Hydrology"] = np.sqrt(data["Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology"]**2 + data["Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology"]**2)
    data["Hillshade_Mean"] = (data["Hillshade_9am"] + data["Hillshade_Noon"] + data["Hillshade_3pm"])/3
    data["Is_Extremely_Stony"] = np.where((data["Soil_Type1"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type24"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type25"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type27"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type28"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type29"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type30"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type31"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type32"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type33"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type34"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type36"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type37"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type38"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type39"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type40"]==1), 1, 0)
    data["Is_Very_Stony"] = np.where((data["Soil_Type2"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type9"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type18"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type26"]==1), 1, 0)
    data["Is_Rubbly"] = np.where((data["Soil_Type3"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type4"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type5"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type10"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type11"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type13"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type22"]==1), 1, 0)
    
#     https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-forest-cover-types-with-the-machine-learning-workflow-1f6f049bf4df
    data['Mean_Elevation_Vertical_Distance_Hydrology'] = (data['Elevation'] + data['Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology'])/2
    data['Mean_Distance_Hydrology_Firepoints'] = (data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology'] + data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points'])/2
    data['Mean_Distance_Hydrology_Roadways'] = (data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology'] + data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways'])/2
    data['Mean_Distance_Firepoints_Roadways'] = (data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points'] + data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways'])/2
    return data

x_train = add_features(x_train)
x_test = add_features(x_test)
```

Comment: You will have to use different methods to find how different variables correlate with each other. For numeric to numeric variables you can use "pearson" method which is available in pandas (df.corr). For categorical to categorical variables you can use Crammer's V. The trickiest one is to find how categorical and numeric columns relate with each other. Check this article https://medium.com/@outside2SDs/an-overview-of-correlation-measures-between-categorical-and-continuous-variables-4c7f85610365

Comment: Yea! In this case, all variables are numeric. What I don't know is how to see the correction of the x_train dataframe with the y_train dataframe. In other words, see the correlation of variables from one base to another.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching functions and found `DataFrame.corrwith(other, axis=0, drop=False, method='pearson')`. With it I can make the correlation of my training base with my base which contains only the answer variable.

Here's the code:

```
train, test = load_train_test_data(PATH)

variables = train.drop("Cover_Type", axis=1)
var_resp = train["Cover_Type"].copy()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(variables, var_resp, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

# Feature engineering:
# Hypotenuse_Distance_To_Hydrology - sqrt((Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology)^2 + (Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology)^2) using Pythagoras's theorem
# Hillshade_Mean - (Hillshade_9am + Hillshade_Noon + Hillshade_3pm)/3
# Is_Extremely_Stony - if Type_Soil 1, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 then 1 else 0
# Is_Very_Stony - if Type_Soil 2, 9, 18, 26 then 1 else 0
# Is_Rubbly - if Type_Soil 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 22 then 1 else 0
def add_features(data):
    data["Hypotenuse_Distance_To_Hydrology"] = np.sqrt(data["Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology"]**2 + data["Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology"]**2)
    data["Hillshade_Mean"] = (data["Hillshade_9am"] + data["Hillshade_Noon"] + data["Hillshade_3pm"])/3
    data["Is_Extremely_Stony"] = np.where((data["Soil_Type1"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type24"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type25"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type27"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type28"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type29"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type30"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type31"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type32"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type33"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type34"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type36"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type37"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type38"]==1)
                                          | (data["Soil_Type39"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type40"]==1), 1, 0)
    data["Is_Very_Stony"] = np.where((data["Soil_Type2"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type9"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type18"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type26"]==1), 1, 0)
    data["Is_Rubbly"] = np.where((data["Soil_Type3"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type4"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type5"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type10"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type11"]==1) | (data["Soil_Type13"]==1)
                                    | (data["Soil_Type22"]==1), 1, 0)
    
#     https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-forest-cover-types-with-the-machine-learning-workflow-1f6f049bf4df
    data['Mean_Elevation_Vertical_Distance_Hydrology'] = (data['Elevation'] + data['Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology'])/2
    data['Mean_Distance_Hydrology_Firepoints'] = (data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology'] + data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points'])/2
    data['Mean_Distance_Hydrology_Roadways'] = (data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology'] + data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways'])/2
    data['Mean_Distance_Firepoints_Roadways'] = (data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points'] + data['Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways'])/2
    return data

x_train = add_features(x_train)
x_test = add_features(x_test)

corr_with_y = x_train.corrwith(y_train)
corr_with_y

corr = x_train.loc[:, x_train.columns != 'Id'].corr()
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```